# Adding strings collected from JSON request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to make add together strings to assemble a header for a call.

**Step 1:**
`access_token` I get from previous call
Response:

```
{
   "access_token":"abc123",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "expires_in":3600
}
```

I collect the token like so:

```
access_token = json.loads(r.content)["access_token"]
```

**Step 2:** I assemble headers for next call

```
authorisation = "Bearer " + access_token
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': authorisation,
        'Cookie': cookie
        }
```

`Authorisation` variable should have this format:
`'Authorization':'Bearer abc123'`. When I use `authorisation = "Bearer " + access_token` the assembled string is wrong:

```
'Authorization':'Bearer' 'abc123'
```

looks like python makes extra `'` in between `Bearer` and `abc123`.

I cannot go around that problem. I tried:

1. If do without space after bearer it does not make extra parenthesis.
2. Str(access_token) also does not work
3. .strip() also does not work

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange problem, try using f-strings instead and see what happens. `authorization = f"Bearer {access_token}"'

Comment: @justgoodin Same result

Comment: do you see a correct string if you put print(authorisation) in your code? have you tried using single quotes around Bearer?

Comment: found the mistake: instead of using print() i used pprint() when printing the result...lol